# Use MySQL database like SQLite in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Im developing a little web application  with PHP and MySQL but in the computer that im working, i cannot install Database Servers like SQL Server or MySQL Server.
I've worked with SQLITE and its amazing, NO INSTALL just the DABATASE AND THE CORRECT LIBRARIES.

DO you know if there's a way to work like this with MySQL Databases ?

Thanks.
NOTE: I 've tried .sdf of Microsoft SQL COmpact but i dont wanna use Microsoft products for now.

Comment: Well, you either install it on a Live USB, or bring an OpenWRT router with you.

Comment: Well nice idea but i like to work with fully relation database :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. MySQL is not a file based Database.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have to install MySQL (if you want MySQL) like you install Php in your computer.
Or you can get both of them in one app like: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/

Is these what you want?